# How can I have a multi-module Maven project without specifying the version all over the place?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am currently learning Maven for a specific project. In this project, I need to have multiple modules (in the sense of a collection of classes and resources) that depend on each-other. Specifically, I need a module to store the classes of a public-facing API (the API is a Java API, as the desktop program can load addons at runtime), another for a set of common classes that are shared between the client and server but that are not part of the API, and of course the client and server themselves need a module each.

Using the system that I used before Maven (IntelliJ Idea's build system), I would simply create different modules and setup dependencies using IntelliJ's GUI. This works well because I can then put the whole IntelliJ Idea project in a git repository, and keep everything nicely tracked together with no fuss and no problems.

When researching how to do this in Maven, however, I ran into some problems. Maven's documentation has [a section](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_build_more_than_one_project_at_once) that seems to explain how to accomplish something similar, but its technique seems to have two problems. When Each sub-project, with its own pom.xml, needs to specify the version of the other sub-projects that it depends on¹. This implies that I need to make many changes all over the project whenever the version changes. This will (hopefully) be quite frequent. As it is perfectly plausible that my project will grow to have hundreds of modules, this is obviously impractical.

Additionally, based on my other research, it seems like a Maven repository is involved in the documented technique. Specifically, it seems like when, for example, the API module is built to be included in the client and server modules it will first be placed in a local repository and then the client and server modules will retrieve it from there. This sounds problematic as the API module will also be published in a public repository (maybe Maven central, I haven't really thought about this too much -- but it will be public in a repo), and this repository step seems like it could end up building the client and server with a published jar rather than the local one, which is problematic for many reasons. (eg. if a developer is making local changes to the api jar, building half the project without those changes is a problem).

Is there some better way to combine multiple modules to mitigate these problems (versions all over the place, and getting wrong jars from repos)? Is it better to modify the technique in the linked documentation instead? Am I misunderstanding something and the problems don't exist?

I have checked DuckDuckGo and all relevant questions that I can find on StackOverflow, and none address either of the two aforementioned problems.

¹:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: If all your subprojects increment their versions in sync with each other, then your project structure is probably wrong and what you call subprojects are really just modules within a single project.  The point of dependencies is to allow each project to have its own development trajectory.  If B depends on A, then it uses A's API. When A publishes a new version you don't want B to automatically get the new version of A until you've confirmed the changes in A don't break B.

Comment: @JimGarrison They absolutely are modules within a single project, but Maven's documentation suggests to me that the best way to handle that is with the technique in the linked documentation. For example, the first sentence in that link is "The concept of dealing with multiple modules is built in to Maven," which clearly talks about modules. I am 100% open to better ways to do this with Maven, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your multi-module project, you usually use just one version for all modules. This means that you can define dependencies between modules with `<version>${project.version}</version>` where the property `${project.version}$` is resolved during the build. Maven builds all the modules in the correct order.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on the last point? I think that you are trying to address my concern of getting some of the jars from a public repository, but what you have said is not specific enough for me to know if it solves my problem or how to apply it.

Comment: Your "public repository concern" is not clear to me. When you build all modules, and declare the version as I said, these modules will only use the given version of other modules.

Comment: My concern is that when, for example, the client module (in the example in the question) attempts to find the jar of the API module, it will find the published one instead of the local one, as they will both have identical versions along the lines of 1.0-SNAPSHOT. When you say that your technique ensures that the correct version of modules are used, are you saying that I am mistaken that what I described is a concern, even if the versions are identical?

Comment: This cannot happen because if A depends on B, then B is build _before_ A, so the 1.0-SNAPSHOT of B will already be the new version when A asks for it.

Comment: When B is already built and A attempts to find B's jar, what stops it from finding it in a remote repo and then stopping the search, thus never seeing the local B jar?

Comment: The local jar is the newest. So it wins (furthermore, there might be even some magic in the multi-maven build that ensures that). You do not need to worry here.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. I'll accept your answer, but I think that it would be better to include that information via an edit.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your first question: you can create a parent pom over your whole project. In this parent pom you can add a dependencyManagement section where you can list your own modules with their version. In your modules you then only need to specify the dependeny without the version.

Here an example:

in parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>yourgroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>yourmoduleA</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>yourgroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>yourmoduleB</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and if your module A uses module B, you can add in pom of module A

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>yourgroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>yourmoduleB</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: I am very new to maven. So, while what you are saying makes sense, it isn't detailed enough for me to use. Can you edit your answer to include either more details (with code) or a link to a place where I can find those details?